# Java REST endpoint to return any database columns

Tags: java, database, rest

Lets say I have a postgres table named Employee with the following columns:

- ID
- FirstName
- LastName
- Employment
- Date
- Manager
- Department

I am interested in having a REST endpoint such that `/employee/{ID}` will return all information for that particular employee in JSON format, but if I specify `/employee/{ID}/FirstName` then it'd return particular employee's first name only in JSON format, `/employee/{ID}/LastName` would return the employee's last name in JSON format, and so on.  Is there a good way to implement this instead of implementing an endpoint for accessing each column?  Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you do it with a single end-point, ie. `/employee/{id}/{attribute}` and map `attribute` to a column name?

Comment: I believe that is the solution I am looking for.  But does that also mean in my endpoint function I'd have to have a mapping function that goes from the attribute to retrieve the columns?

I guess my main question is, right now there are 7 columns in the database and I can define it as you've mentioned, but if there is an 8th column that gets added in the future, is it possible that we can create the endpoint now so we don't have to alter the code when the new column is added?

Comment: When I use `{attribute}` in the endpoint, it's a wild-card - typically implemented using a `PathVariable` (or equivalent). Make sure whatever library you are using for REST / MVC supports this. If it does, then you'll need to write your mapping. The mapping will need to change if you add a new column, but your endpoint won't.

Comment: Thanks I believe the "mapping will need to change if you add a new column" was what I really wanted verification on.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to solve this, is to use a request param instead of querying for the URL. Using a param like `fields` you would have an URL like `/employee/{id}?fields=FirstName,LastName`. Using the code below you could have a `Map<String, Object>` that would be serialized to a JSON with your data. Like this:

```
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> getPerson(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestParam("fields") String fields) throws Exception {
    return personService.getPersonFields(id, fields);
}

@Service
class PersonService {

    public Map<String, Object> getPersonFields(Long personId, String fields) throws Exception {
        final Person person = personRepository.findById(personId);
        if (person == null) {
            throw new Exception("Person does not exists!");
        }

        String[] fieldsArray = fields.split(",");
        Map<String, Field> personFields = Arrays.stream(person.getClass().getFields()).collect(Collectors.toMap(Field::getName, field -> field);

        Map<String, Object> personFieldsReturn = new HashMap<>();
        for (String field : fieldsArray) {
            if (personFields.containsKey(field)) {
                personFields.get(field).setAccessible(true);
                personFieldsReturn.put(field, personFields.get(field).get(person));
                personFields.get(field).setAccessible(false);
            }
        }

        return personFieldsReturn;
    }

}
```

This is not a good solution though. But it should work.

Comment: This is a risky solution - you would be better off not exposing column names on your API.

Comment: Well, use it to map your DTO into the controller instead of map the entity into the service. It's the same logic.

Comment: This way you can define an abstract controller and centralize the logic of mapping fields of all DTOs. Do you see my point?

Comment: I see your point. However database columns (or fields) belong in the data access layer and should not appear in controllers. Any mapping between entity attributes (part of the model) to DB concepts belong in the data access layer.

Answer (score 0):

So as @dave mentioned in a comment you can have a REST endpoint `/employee/{ID}/{column}` and in your controller you will have a mapping between value of `{column}` argument and actual column name in database. If you do not want to redeploy your application when mapping changes you can put it in a separate properties file on a server outside of your jar/war and you can also add an additional endpoint to either reload mapping form file on a server or an endpoint that will allow to upload and parse a file with mapping directly to your application.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `RepositoryRestResource` from `Spring Data`.

First of all, create your entity:

```
public class Employee {
    //props
}
```

Afterthat create `Employee Repository`:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "employee", path = "employee")
public interface EmployeeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Employee, Long> {

    List<Employee> findByLastName(@Param("firstName") String firstName);

}
```

And that's all, you will get:

- discoverable REST API for your domain model using HAL as media type.
- collection, item and association resources representing your mode.
- paginating and sorting

and so on.

Check out the docs:

[Spring Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/)

[Spring Dc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/repository-resources.html)

[Spring Data Rest Project](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-rest)